# scala import error from Play starter projects

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

im getting this error when i try to import play 2.6.12 scala starter project in intellij

```
Scala plugin version:2017.2.13

Intellij version:Ultimate 2017.2.1
```

https://www.playframework.com/download#starters

```
Applying State transformations org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks from /Users/qdt624/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.2/Scala/launcher/sbt-structure-1.1.jar
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks$
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.getObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.BasicCommands$.$anonfun$call$5(BasicCommands.scala:203)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:295)
[error]     at sbt.BasicCommands$.$anonfun$call$2(BasicCommands.scala:203)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:134)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:130)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:153)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:136)
[error]     at sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:242)
[error]     at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:248)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:136)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:136)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:129)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:107)
[error]     at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:101)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:57)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:42)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:34)
[error]     at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:113)
[error]     at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:76)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks$
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[info] shutting down server
[INFO] [04/05/2018 00:47:35.443] [Thread-3] [CoordinatedShutdown(akka://sbt-web)] Starting coordinated shutdown from JVM shutdown hook
```

I have tried deleting .idea folder and reimporting the project

Answer (score 1):

This problem [has been fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13283) and the fix will be available in the next release of the IntelliJ Scala plugin (2018.1.9+) or right now in the Nightly releases.

As a workaround until then, you can close the project and do a fresh import.